# How to set & fetch fields of inner class in another class

Tags: java, spring, static, inner-classes

```java
package com.pr.trio;

import java.util.List;

public class lalala {

     private List<SegmentationFieldValue> segmentationFieldValues;

      
       public static class SegmentationFieldValue {
          private Integer segmentationFieldId;
          private Integer segmentationFieldGroupId;
          private String value;
        public Integer getSegmentationFieldId() {
            return segmentationFieldId;
        }
        public void setSegmentationFieldId(Integer segmentationFieldId) {
            this.segmentationFieldId = segmentationFieldId;
        }
        public Integer getSegmentationFieldGroupId() {
            return segmentationFieldGroupId;
        }
        public void setSegmentationFieldGroupId(Integer segmentationFieldGroupId) {
            this.segmentationFieldGroupId = segmentationFieldGroupId;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
       }


    public List<SegmentationFieldValue> getSegmentationFieldValues() {
        return segmentationFieldValues;
    }


    public void setSegmentationFieldValues(List<SegmentationFieldValue> segmentationFieldValues) {
        this.segmentationFieldValues = segmentationFieldValues;
    }
       
}
```

```java
package com.pr.trio;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class kk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        lalala l1 = new lalala();
        
        
        //currently passed as an empty array, want to set SegmentationFieldId & value here from inner class
        l1.setSegmentationFieldValues(Arrays.asList());  
        
        //lalala.SegmentationFieldValue.this.setSegmentationFieldId(15);
        
        
        System.out.println(l1.getSegmentationFieldValues());
        


}
}
```

So here, I'm not able to pass values for the segmentation field instead of the empty array, gives an error. So how can I set the values from the inner class fields & pass it to my list?

Comment: Static inner classes exist independently of their outer class. I think you just need to remove the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as your `SegmentationFieldValue` class is `public`, it's trivial to use it inside another class, there are basically two ways to go about this:

The first is to import the inner class:

```java
import com.pr.trio.lalala.SegmentationFieldValue;
```

The second is to qualify the classname whenever you use it:

```java
lalala.SegmentationFieldValue a = new lalala.SegmentationFieldValue();
```

You can then call the setters on this class, and use the objects in your call to `setSegmentationFieldValues`:

```java
lalala.SegmentationFieldValue a = new lalala.SegmentationFieldValue();
a.setSegmentationFieldId(1);
a.setSegmentationFieldGroupId(1);
a.setValue("a");

lalala.SegmentationFieldValue b = new lalala.SegmentationFieldValue();
b.setSegmentationFieldId(2);
b.setSegmentationFieldGroupId(1);
b.setValue("b");

l1.setSegmentationFieldValues(Arrays.asList(a, b));
```

Judging from your comment code, you also seem to be looking for a shorthand way to add an element to your list. A simple implementation could look like this (in class `lalala`):

```java
public void addSegmentationFieldValue(Integer id, Integer groupId, String value)
{
    if (segmentationFieldValues == null)
    {
        segmentationFieldValues = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    SegmentationFieldValue result = new SegmentationFieldValue();
    result.setSegmentationFieldId(id);
    result.setSegmentationFieldGroupId(groupId);
    result.setValue(value);
    segmentationFieldValues.add(result);
}
```

After which you can do the following in the `main` method of `k1`:

```java
l1.addSegmentationFieldValue(1, 1, "a");
```